# Does Django formsets prevent editing hidden fields with id?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Formset is created with **modelformset_factory** and uses regular **ModelForm**, I'm also using **django-crispy-forms**. Why modifying form-X-id hidden field value from A to B (both A and B ids exist in database) does not modify that record?

Inside view **form_valid** method I can see that field value is B, so I would expect that record A attributes would be the same as record B, but thankfully it does not happen, instead view proceeds as if nothing went wrong, why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that record A and record B dont get all their attributes exchanged and thats why you cant see any difference ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I had this table opened in Dbeaver, both records are untouched.

Comment: Is save() run on the model ?